# Why is tcsendbreak() necessary for serial communication to start working?

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver

We are migrating from an older OS `(OpenSuse 10.2)` to `Ubuntu 16.04`, and one of our applications communicates via a serial port. Communication stopped working on Ubunutu, but with a small hack(?) it does start working. That hack is to send a `tcsendbreak(`) right after the call to open, like so:

```
fd = open(pname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY); //pname becomes /dev/ttyS6
if (fd < 0)
{
    printf("Couldnt open comms port \"%s\".\n", pname);
    return SYSERR;
}
if (tcsendbreak(fd, 0) < 0)
{
    printf("tcsendbreak error\n");
}
```

After doing this everything runs normally. I've tried doing a tcflush at various points (without the tcsendbreak), that didn't make a difference.

What are some reasons why the tcsendbreak would allow communication to be established? Any ideas of what to try without using the tcsendbreak? Trying to understand why its needed, and if there is an underlying issue that this break skips past.

We set the modes the following way:

```
int r = 0;
struct termios port_opt, *popt;

r |= tcgetattr(fd, &original_port_options);
port_opt = original_port_options;
popt = &port_opt;
cfmakeraw(&port_opt);
/* parity/framing errors come in as nulls. */
popt->c_iflag |= (IGNBRK);
popt->c_cflag |= (CLOCAL);
popt->c_cc[VMIN] = 0;   /* ignored by line discipline. */
popt->c_cc[VTIME] = 1;  /* ignored by line discipline. */
popt->c_cflag |= CREAD; //enable receiver
r |= cfsetispeed(popt, B19200); 
popt->c_cflag &= ~(PARENB);/* turn off parity. */
popt->c_cflag = (popt->c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8; /* 8 bits. */
popt->c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; /* only 1 stop bit. */
r |= cfsetospeed(popt, B19200);
r |= tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, popt);
if (r != 0)
    gos_panic("Cant set comms driver parameters");
```

Additionally, we also set a line discipline:

```
r = ioctl(fd, TIOCGETD, &old_line_discipline);
if (r != 0)
    old_line_discipline = -1;
r = map_line_discipline("LINE_DISC", 27);
r = ioctl(fd, TIOCSETD, &r);
```

Note that communication works when sending the tcsendbreak before setting all these modes.

Comment: *"Why is tcsendbreak() necessary ..."* -- It shouldn't.  Is your program  POSIX compliant?  Failing to follow  [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) is one way to break portability.

Comment: I have been reviewing that page, nothing seems out of ordinary with how were are setting the modes.

Comment: *"nothing seems out of ordinary ..."* -- Then post your code for review, since you didn't bother to answer my question.  Probably 99% of the termios code I see posted fails to adhere to POSIX guidelines in varying degrees.

Comment: @sawdust i posted how we are setting the modes, thanks

Comment: So your code does fall into the exceptional "1%" of conforming code.  Two lines involving PARENB and CS8 are superfluous.  The sole termios issue I see is that CRTSCTS in c_cflag is left to whatever the undefined state is.  The other salient issue is the new revelation that you're using a custom line discipline.  That can make your question unanswerable.

Comment: I am also seeing the same behavior in my application. I am running with kernel `4.4.0`. Previously, I was running on `3.9.2` kernel

Comment: if you have time look [man perror](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) better error message